# Dynamically loaded SVG doesn't seem to execute onload functions anymore

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, gwt, svg

I have an existing application that is written using GWT as a "single page application". One of the many things that can happen is that a user-provided SVG is loaded into the page for viewing. The user can (from the SVG) call functions in the main application to retrieve or set values.

Since quite recently (not sure exactly when), Chrome no longer executes the **onload** when the SVG is loaded from GWT. But older versions of Chrome does, Opera does and many (all?) versions of Firefox does. IE10/11 are also working as expected, according to a user.

Something seems to have changed in Chrome, and rather recently...

Loading of the SVG looks like;

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel;

@UiField
HTMLPanel svgContainer;

@Override
public void setSvgContent( String svgContent )
{
    clearView();
    Element containerElement = svgContainer.getElement();
    containerElement.setInnerHTML( svgContent );
```

And even the simplest SVG's onload isn't executed anymore;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="744.09448819" height="1052.3622047" version="1.1" onload="alert('Niclas1')">
    <text style="font-size:40px" x="150" y="150" 
          onload="alert('Niclas2')"
          onclick="alert('Niclas3')">
        <tspan x="150" y="150">##0.0°C</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Simply, none of the **onload** gets executed, but the **onclick** is fine.

Does anyone knows of any changes that has happened in this space over the last few months??

Does anyone have any ideas of work-arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome 34 has a serious bug issue with svg, your problem may be related to:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362354
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=361576

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related, other than perhaps "many SVG problems".

Comment: @NiclasHedhman I think it likely is related. I am experiencing similar issues with M34 of chrome.

Comment: Safari is having same issue. Is it originating in webkit?